# Getting maven error while building java project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am just created one sample maven project which have the code to convert string json to java object using gson:

when I run the maven build it is giving below error,anyone help me out:

I am trying with open network only.

---

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-rest-client: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.naresh:test-rest-client:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.4: Could not transfer artifact com.google.code.gson:gson:pom:1.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server -> [Help 1]

Thanks,
Naresh.

Comment: Are you using any kind of proxy? Any custom repository or configuration? Are you able to open the artifact in the repo url?

Comment: This kind of error usually is related to these points I have mentioned, if you can try in another network.

Comment: Can you access the site (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/), do a wget and see what you get or ping and see if it returns any errors.

Comment: If you're using organizational network, then there is chance that there are proxy settings. All you need to do is add proxy address, username, password in your setting.xml file. Then it will allow downloading the dependencies.